# Why does adding overflow-scroll remove the bullets on my tailwind-styled <ul> items?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm making a website using react and tailwind. I want to add a vertical scrollbar to a list in a section of my page, but when I do, the bullets disappear. Why is this happening?

```
<ul className="list-disc overflow-y-auto h-80 space-y-3 text-sm w-full sm:text-md items-start">
          {experience.points.map((point, i) => (
            <li key={i}>{point}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
```

I've tried using overflow-y-scroll instead but it has the same effect. I've also tried adjusting the margins of the list container but that doesn't work either. The bullets appear when I don't use any overflow utility. For now, I've just added them to each list-item string manually but I'm curious as to why this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

what you are missing is the css rule that sets the counter inside or outside 
in **tailwind** 3 it's the class `list-inside` 
plain **css**: `list-style-position: inside;`
being it set outside by default, setting the overflow cuts them out

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<ul className="list-disc overflow-auto h-80 space-y-3 text-sm w-full sm:text-md items-start p-2">
      {experience.points.map((point, i) => (
        <li key={i} className='list-disc p-2'>{point}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Comment: this does make my list look better but the bullet points still won't show up. FWIW I also tried using list-decimal but same result.